# How to specify the expiry time of a Redis object in .NET Core?

Tags: redis, asp.net-core

I find there are "absexp","sldexp" and "data" fields in a Redis hash key.

I can  use _radius.setString/getString to set and get the value of field data. But how can I modify the field "absexp" in the ASP.NET core project?

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to change the cache expiration?

Use code like this to create an DistributedCacheEntryOptions object and assign when you set the value to cache so:

```
var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions(); // create options object
options.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)); // 1 minute sliding expiration
_cache.SetString(cacheKey, value, options); // set key value pair with options
// your value will now expire after one minute
```

Absolute expiration can be set with a similar method on the option object if you don't want sliding expiration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am having problem with this one. Do I expect the data (keys) deleted from the Redis server after 1 min since the last request has been processed? Because - When I am setting the TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), I am hoping the values should not be returned from the Cache as it should be deleted

Comment: @PrateekGangopadhyay It is possible. SetSlidingExpiration will reset the expiration offset if the data is accessed. If you want it to be deleted in 30 seconds no matter what then use the `options.SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))` and it be deleted in 30 seconds no matter how many times it is accessed.